# hyper-v failed to start worker process: ran out of memory 0x800700E

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2016

I have a Windows Server 2016 DataCenter with 0.5TB of RAM (there is a 497GB of RAM currently available) and I have three hyper-v virtual machines there. They have been running perfectly until we added a few discs into the physical server. Suddenly I cannot start any of them and even newly created VM cannot be started as well. Every VM request maximum 16GB of RAM. I receive the "failed to start worker process: ran out of memory 0x800700E" error.

[image]

I have tried to alter the virtual images to the minimal configuration possible (one processor, dynamic RAM with 512MB min memory) without any success. There are no Hyper-V events in the log. What can be possibly wrong?

Comment: Looks like the Hyper-V service thinking that you don't have any free memory to start the VM. Can you check the non-paged pool? Did you try to restart either host or/and Hyper-V service? However, maybe the issue is related to the disk provisioning? Could you take a look and make sure that you have enough disk space in case if you are using dynamic VHDX?

Comment: @Strepsils the restart of the host helped ...

Comment: Boot your hosts, Hyper-V is not as stable or reliable as vmware.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today.  I checked Drive space, which had 800GB free so that should be way more than plenty.
Then I remembered that I had switched settings to dynamic memory allocation and upped the virtual processors from 1 to 2 the last time I was playing with the VM.  I don't know enough about hyper-v to understand why that would affect it this way but going back to a fixed amount of memory (8GB) and a single virtual processor, I was able to start the machine.

I don't know if this is relevant, but there were a bunch of windows updates queued up for installation so that may have affected the necessary memory to start it?
I am VERY new to the whole world of administering VM's in any hypervisor.
I just thought I would share my specific experience to this helpful gang of people in case it may help others somehow.